# MVC .NET User takes data from other user if both call same function

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 different logged in users. I go to the same page in both accounts, and hit refresh in the same time.

On that page I have ajax call which calls function:

```
public JsonResult GetAppointments()
    {
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        var eventList = from a in db.Appointments
                        where a.UserId == userId
                         select new
                         {
                         ...
```

So it should return different appointments, based on userId.

But for some reason, one user gets data from other user. (On page I get same data for both users)

It looks like that function call from first user occupied thread, and second user got data from that thread, not from his function call.

Anyone knows how is this possible and why is this happening?

EDIT:
When this happends, I hit logout for second user and get: "The anti-forgery cookie token and form field token do not match." error. It seems that somehow second user got form field token from first user also, don't know how.

Comment: It has nothing to do with your method. Try it in 2 different browsers simultaneously. Probably you logged out and logged in with having a different tab stay open with the previous account. That's why you would get conflicting results.

Comment: Yes, I tried it in 2 different browsers simultaneously, login with 2 different accounts, and then go to same page, and get this problem. I cleared cache, cookies before to be sure, and tested this multiple times, to be sure that problem is there, and its happening every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found problem.

On controller I had:

```
OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 1, VaryByParam = "")
```

I changed Duration = 0 and everything works fine now.